# SAS - PROC SQL: How to show predicted values in a table using PROC REG?

Tags: sas

I have run a regression on a data set. I would like to then add the predicted values into the original data set table. I would like the PredictedMS_Diff values to be added to the PROPreg_CSR_final dataset.

```
proc reg data=PROPreg_CSR_final outest=outest_model_1 covout plots=diagnostics(stats=(default aic 
sbc));
title "CSR Final";
FinalCSR:MODEL MS_Diff_CSR=Rank_Delta_prop;
Output PREDICTED=PredictedMS_Diff
run;
title;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your output statement does not have an OUT= option so the data set is named by SAS.  Also missing a semicolon.

Output PREDICTED=PredictedMS_Diff

If that has worked it would have been a copy of the input data with PredictedMS_Diff added.

```
proc reg data=sashelp.class;
   model weight=height;
   output out=pred predicted=p residual=r;
   run;
```

[image]